# Multi-index setup for Dataframe - pandas/Jupyter

Tags: python, pandas, jupyter-notebook

## Convert list to dictionary

```
    self.internal_output_df = pd.DataFrame(list)
```

## Create labels

```
    labels = [[str(i)] + [str(i) + '_' + str(x) for x in range(1, self.num_matches+1)]
              for i in range(1, len(self.df) + 1)]
    labels = [y for x in labels for y in x]
    self.internal_output_df['match'] = labels


    # Select final variables to display
    variables = [
        'a',
        'b',
        'c',
        'd',
        'e',
        'f',
        'g',
        'h'
    ]


    self.internal_output_df = self.internal_output_df.set_index('match')[variables]
```

"""Sample Data Format"""
Format that I'm getting:
[image: Output that I'm getting]

Format that I want to generate:
[image: Output that I want to generate]

"""
QUESTION:
I'm getting the label output as:

```
Row1: ['1', '1_1', '1_2', '1_3', '1_4', '1_5','2', '2_1', '2_2', '2_3', '2_4', '2_5'] 
Row2: ['1', '1_1', '1_2', '1_3', '1_4', '1_5','2', '2_1', '2_2', '2_3', '2_4', '2_5']
Row3: ['1', '1_1', '1_2', '1_3', '1_4', '1_5','2', '2_1', '2_2', '2_3', '2_4', '2_5']
Row4: ['1', '1_1', '1_2', '1_3', '1_4', '1_5','2', '2_1', '2_2', '2_3', '2_4', '2_5']
Row5: ['1', '1_1', '1_2', '1_3', '1_4', '1_5','2', '2_1', '2_2', '2_3', '2_4', '2_5']
Row6: ['1', '1_1', '1_2', '1_3', '1_4', '1_5','2', '2_1', '2_2', '2_3', '2_4', '2_5']
Row7: ['1', '1_1', '1_2', '1_3', '1_4', '1_5','2', '2_1', '2_2', '2_3', '2_4', '2_5']
Row8: ['1', '1_1', '1_2', '1_3', '1_4', '1_5','2', '2_1', '2_2', '2_3', '2_4', '2_5']
Row9: ['1', '1_1', '1_2', '1_3', '1_4', '1_5','2', '2_1', '2_2', '2_3', '2_4', '2_5']
Row10: ['1', '1_1', '1_2', '1_3', '1_4', '1_5','2', '2_1', '2_2', '2_3', '2_4', '2_5']
Row11: ['1', '1_1', '1_2', '1_3', '1_4', '1_5','2', '2_1', '2_2', '2_3', '2_4', '2_5']
Row12: ['1', '1_1', '1_2', '1_3', '1_4', '1_5','2', '2_1', '2_2', '2_3', '2_4', '2_5']
```

So the values of dataframe are getting repeated for every row in dataframe.

I want to get the unique values of label output as single row for rows in dataframe as below format:

```
Row1: 1
Row2: 1_1
Row3: 1_2
Row4: 1_3
Row5: 1_4
Row6: 1_5
Row7: 2
Row8: 2_1
Row9: 2_2
Row10: 2_3
Row11: 2_4
Row12: 2_5
```

So I do not want the rows to repeat the same values in every row.
"""

Comment: Can you please improve your question with sample data set

Comment: Added the images of the output format that I'm getting as compared to the output format that I want to generate.  Only the column named 'match' has an issue, the rest of the output looks good with the reference code that I have posted.  Platform info: Using Windows 10, Jupyter notebook from Anaconda with Python 3.7